# Sorting ArrayList in n category Java

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of type `ArrayList<Food>`. This `Food` class has two variables `name` and `timing`, `timing` can be `breakfast`, `lunch` and `dinner`. Data coming to `ArrayList` is from a `JSON` which has not sorted it in anyway.

I want to sort this list into 4 categories.

**Example:**

```
Rice,breakfast
Hotdog, dinner
carrot shake, breakfast
soup, lunch
chocolate, dinner
```

**TO:**

```
Rice,breakfast
carrot shake, breakfast
soup, lunch
Hotdog, dinner
chocolate, dinner
```

Comment: this isn't sorting you are basically wants to create 4 categories mean 4 list.because how would a single list help you where fist 2 items are from 1st category next 3 from 2 , next 10 from 3rd category so on

Comment: @PavneetSingh One doesn't need more than one list for this question here. If you want to know how sorting works in this case, then also see the linked question (and its answers) by R. Zagórski.

Comment: @Tom i know how it works,thanks , if sorting is really the concern here in the way mentioned then the far better optimizations could be done on server side maybe you would like to give the logic as answer as well in support of your comment.any help will be appreciated Mr.Tom

Comment: hey should i do it on server side or on my android app ? any suggesstions ? @Tom

Comment: This depends on how many different sortings you like to implement here. If you *always* need this list in that sorting, then prefer server side. If you different ways of sorting and the sorting is a client specific detail, then the client should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Comparator`. Example:

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {

            return e1.startsOn.compareTo(e2.startsOn);
        }
    });
```

Where: `eventList` is an `arrayList` and the Type of object is `Event`.
You can use the property of your object that you want to compare and that's it.

Best regards.

Comment: Hey thanks for prompt reply, i will just try it and mark it as answer if this solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(foodlist, new Comparator<Food>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Food f1, Food f2) {
            if (f1.timing.equalsIgnoreCase("") || f2.timing.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                return -1;
            else if (f1.timing.equalsIgnoreCase("dinner") && f2.timing.equalsIgnoreCase("lunch"))
                return 1;
            else if (f1.timing.equalsIgnoreCase("lunch") && f2.timing.equalsIgnoreCase("dinner"))
                return -1;
            else
                return f1.timing.compareToIgnoreCase(f2.timing);

        }
    });
```